# Lagrange polynomial and derivative problem

Tags: polynomials, derivatives, matlab, error-function

I need to code this function in matlab

$$L'(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} f_k l_k(x)  $$

Where's $l_k$ looks like this

$$l_k(x) = \sum^{n}_{j=0, j \neq k} \frac{\prod^{n}_{i=0}(x - x_i)}{(x - x_k)(x-x_j)\prod^{n}_{i=0, i \neq k} (x_k - x_i)} $$

Well I got an array of $f_k, k = 1,\dots,n$ (there are results of error function $erf(x)$ in some points). So I wrote two functions.

First - to find $ l_k$ in some point (in arguments: `res_arr` array with $f_k$, $x$ - some point, `k` it's step in $\sum_{k}$)

```
function lDiffout = lDiff(res_arr, x, k)

n = size(res_arr,2);
result = 0;
p1 =1;
p2 =1;

%   П(x - x_i)
    for i = 1:n 
        p1 = p1*(x - res_arr(i));
    end;
%    П(x_k - x_i)   
    for i = 1:n 
        if(k ~= i)
          p2 = p2*(res_arr(k) - res_arr(i));
        end
    end;


for j=1:n
     p_res = p1/p2;  %П(x - x_i)/П(x_k - x_i) 
    if(j ~= k)
       p_rd = (x - res_arr(k))*(x - res_arr(j));% (x - x_k)(x - x_j)
       result = result + p_res/p_rd; % += П(x - x_i)/ (x - x_k)(x - x_j)П(x_k - x_i)
    end
end;

lDiffout = result;
end
```

Second to find result
(here  is `start, wstep, final` in arguments it's because of x it's vector (in my situation from 0 to 2 with setp 0.2))

```
 function erdifOut = erfDiff(start, wstep, final, arr_res);
    clc
     cnt = 1;
      for xloop = start:wstep:final 
          erdifOut(cnt) = arr_res(cnt)*lDiff(arr_res, xloop, cnt);
          disp(['in x=', num2str(xloop), ' result is L = ',  num2str(erdifOut(cnt))]);
          cnt = cnt + 1;
      end;
    end
```

But it does not works correctly for some reason. My teacher said that i need to do something with $l_k$ function, make it simpler or something. Please how I can do it? Or maybe something wrong with the code?

Comment: Without any concept of what your input data looks like, it's tough to tell what you mean by "does not work correctly." Are you getting a MATLAB error? Are you getting wrong results?

Comment: @Arkamis
wrong results - NaNs and wierd values

Comment: NaNs mean you have 0/0 division errors.

Comment: oh i tought that `k ~= i`and `j ~= k`  terms helps to avoid such problem ._.

Comment: It would, but you're doing something else wrong, and I'm not terribly inclined to dig through to figure it out :)

Comment: @Arkamis oh np I understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code, I assume all vectors are **row vectors**.

Try to avoid so many loops. MATLAB has plenty of built-in statements to do what you want to do.

To compute $\prod_{i=0}^n x - x_i$, try the following code:

```
% xi = [xi1 xi2 ... ] is a vector of your xi's. x is a scalar value.
delta_x = x - xi; % Now, delta_x is a vector, because a scalar minus a vector returns the element-wise subtraction.
Pn = prod(delta_x);
```

This will give you the product in the numerator.

Assuming $k$ is given as a parameter, we can then write the sum a few different ways. Here is the most straightforward way:

```
S = 0;
for j=1:n
    dxj = delta_x(j); % this is x-xj
    dxk = delta_x(k); % this is x-xk
    y = [xi(k)-xi(1:k-1) xi(k)-xi(k+1:end)]; 
    Pd = prod(y); % This is the product in the numerator
    if j ~= k
        S = S + Pn/(dxj*dxk*Pd);
    end
end
```

This should give you what you want for $l_k$.

We can actually do better (see my comment):

```
dxk = delta_x(k); % this is x-xk
y = [xi(k)-xi(1:k-1) xi(k)-xi(k+1:end)]; 
Pd = prod(y); % This is the product in the numerator
delta_x1 = [delta_x(1:k-1) delta_x(k+1:end)];
lk = Pn/(dxk*Pd)*sum(delta_x1.^(-1));
```

These two code snippets are equivalent.

Comment: You should also note that only $1/(x-x_j)$ depends on the index of summation: everything else can be computed outside the sum.

Comment: oh, I am pretty new to MatLab, I wrote some math stuff code on C before(but now  i need to use matlab -_-
What is `y = [xi(k)-xi(1:k-1) xi(k)-xi(k+1:end)]; ` here?

Comment: It looks wierd for me. i mean `xi(1:k-1)` and `xi(k+1:end)` sorry for stupid question :)

Comment: `xi` is a vector, say `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`. Let's say $k = 4$. Then, `xi(1:k-1)` is the first $k-1$ elements in a row vector, so `xi(1:k-1)` returns `[1 2 3]`. Likewise, `xi(k+1:end)` returns everything from $k+1$ to the end of the vector, so `xi(k+1:end)` returns `[5 6 7 8]`. Taken together, `[xi(1:k-1) xi(k+1:end)]` returns `[1 2 3 5 6 7 8]`. Taking the product of this gives you what you want.

Comment: oh thank you I try to made it like you wrote!

Comment: I don't guarantee correctness of your results, or robustness to input data. But this should return your function $l_k(x)$ quite easily.

Comment: @Arakmis oh and do I understood correctly that we work only with $x$ arrray of values and it's indexses `k`?

Comment: @DanilGholtsman In my example, I assume `x` is a **scalar** input value. `xi` is a *row vector* of interpolation nodes.

Comment: yeah but is $x \in xi$?

Comment: No, `x` is your independent variable. `xi` are your interpolation nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thats my realiztion, maybe it would be helpful for somebody in future.
$$L'(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} f_k l_k(z)$$
where $l_k(z)$ is
$$l_k(z) = \sum^{n}_{j=0, j \neq k} \frac{\prod^{n}_{i=0}(z - x_i)}{(z - x_k)(z-x_j)\prod^{n}_{i=0, i \neq k} (x_k - x_i)}$$

```
function [L] = diffL(x, f, z)
%x - intepolation points
%f - some function results in points
%z - points where we executing L function
nL = numel(z); 
n = numel(x);
L = zeros(size(z));
for m = 1:nL %executing L(point) for all points we've got
    sumL = 0;
    for k = 1:n %executing f_k*l_k
       l_k = 0;
        %l_k(z) считаем отдельно
        for j = 1:n
            if(j ~= k)
                %execute l_k numerator
                nom = 1;
                for i = 1:n
                  if((i ~= k)&&(i ~=j)) 
                    nom = nom*(z(m) - x(i));
                  end
                end
                %execute l_k denominator
                denom = 1; 
                for i = 1:n
                    if(i ~= k)
                      denom = denom*(x(k)-x(i));   
                    end
                end
                l_k = l_k + (nom/denom);

            end
        end    
        sumL = sumL + (f(k)*l_k);
    end
    L(m) = L(m) + sumL;
end
end
```