# Derivatives of Lagrange polynomials

Tags: polynomials, derivatives

It seems there is some relationship between Lagrange polynomial and Legendre polynomial. That is Lagrange polynomial can be expressed as a function of Legendre polynomial. If so, I could use this relationship to code up in Matlab. I have been searching the relation for a long time but I did not find it.

My question is: Could anyone tell me the relationship between Lagrange and Legendre polynomial?

I am trying to code up in Matlab to calculate any order derivative of Lagrange polynomial. I know how to calculate the first derivative like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358631/lagrange-polynomial-and-derivative-problem) . But this method need about N FOR loops to calculate Nth derivative.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can find coefficients of Lagrange interpolation polynomial or any of its derivatives relatively easy if you use a matrix form of Lagrange interpolation presented in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", section "Lagrange interpolation". General formula for the polynomial looks as follows
$$
f(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0       & f_0       & f_1       & \cdots & f_n       \\
        x^n     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x^{n-1} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots  & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        x       & x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        1       & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Here $(x_0;f_0)$, $\dots$, $(x_n;f_n)$ are the points it passes through. Using Laplace expansion along the first column you can get expressions for coefficients at $x^i$.

**DERIVATIVE**

If we take derivative of the expression above, it will only act on the first column of the matrix in the numerator (the only one containing $x$'s). One can prove this by expanding determinant in the numerator along the first column, taking derivative and then collecting everything back. As a result, first derivative looks as follows
$$
f'(x) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0             & f_0       & f_1       & \cdots & f_n       \\
        n x^{n-1}     & x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        (n-1) x^{n-2} & x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots        & \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        1             & x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        0             & 1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x_0^n     & x_1^n     & \cdots & x_n^n     \\
        x_0^{n-1} & x_1^{n-1} & \cdots & x_n^{n-1} \\
        \cdots    & \cdots    & \cdots & \cdots    \\
        x_0       & x_1       & \cdots & x_n       \\
        1         & 1         & \cdots & 1         \\
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Higher-order derivatives can be calculated the same way --- you change the first column appropriately, all the rest remains.

**CODE**

I'm afraid, I don't know Matlab good enough to provide you with appropriate code, but I worked with Python a little bit, maybe the following can help (sorry for bad codestyle -- I'm mathematician, not programmer)

```
import numpy as np
# input
x = [0, 2, 4, 5]  # <- x's
y = [2, 5, 7, 7]  # <- y's
# calculating coefficients
M = [[_x**i*(-1)**(i*len(x)) for _x in x] for i in range(len(x))]
C = [np.linalg.det((M+[y]+M)[d:d+len(x)]) for d in range(len(x)+1)]
C = (C / C[0] * (-1)**(len(x)+1) )[1:]
# polynomial lambda-function
poly = lambda _x: sum([C[i] * _x**i for i in range(len(x))])
# output and tests
print("Coefficients:\n", C)
print("TESTING:")
for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
    result = "[OK]" if np.allclose(_y, poly(_x)) else "[ERROR]"
    print(_x, " mapped to: ", poly(_x), " ; expected: ", _y, result)
```

This code calculates coefficients of the Lagrange interpolation polynomial, prints them, and tests that given x's are mapped into expected y's. You can test this code with [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb), so you don't have to install anything. Probably, you can translate it to Matlab and modify so that it computes derivatives (multiply every summand by appropriate constant and modify powers of $x$ accordingly).